# Time Exceeded for a project Euler test

Tags: c, compilation, timeout

I just got into problem solving on project Euler (and a beginner with C code).

Problem 1 states: If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23. Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000. I'm pretty sure my code is correct (or maybe not). Now when I compile my code on a website like codepad.org or ideone.com, it says "time exceeded". I'm guessing the code takes too long to run? Why is this the case?

My solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i, j = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++){   //Traverses all the positive numbers under 1000
        while ( (i % 5 == 0) || (i % 3 == 0)){  
               j = j + i;          //If it's a multiple of 3 or 5 add it to the sum
           }
    }

    printf("The sum of all multiples of 3 and 5 under 1000 is: %d", j);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `while` statement in there which should be an `if` statement.  `while` takes you into an infinite loop as you never change the value of `i` inside the loop when the condition you are testing for is met.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! Haha my mistake. Er, my code still apparently is wrong. (In terms of the problem)

Comment: Solved it. Thanks again!